# Translate labels to render inside the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, translation

I'm making a form in Umbraco 7.7.7 and I'll translate the labels. For this I use the `Display`-attribute and the `UmbracoHelper` class to get access to the dictionary.

```
public class ContactViewModel 
{
    private UmbracoHelper _helper = new UmbracoHelper();

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = _helper.Field("#First name"))] // ← error on this line.
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = _helper.Field("#Last name"))]  // ← error on this line.
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = _helper.Field("#Email"))]      // ← error on this line.
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = _helper.Field("#Message"))]    // ← error on this line.
    public string Message { get; set; }

    // Some other properties...

    public ContactViewModel()
    {
        _helper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
    }
}
```

Here is my code in my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<FormController>("contact", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @(Html.EditorFor<ContactViewModel>())

    <div class="form-control">
        <input type="submit" value="verzenden" class="submit-button" />
    </div>
}
```

But I've got this error on the marked lines:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property `ContactViewModel._helper`.

I've also tried with this code:

```
private static UmbracoHelper _helper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
```

and convert the result of `_helper.Field()` to a string instead of `IHtmlString`.

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = _helper.Field("#First name").ToString())] // ← error on this line.
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

But code now  this error also on the marked lines:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.

**P.S.:** I'm following [this documentation from our.umbraco.org](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/templating/mvc/forms).

Comment: Attributes are metadata and must be know at compile time. `_helper.Field()` is a method and its results cannot be determined until runtime. You need to use a constant, for example `[Display(Name = "First name")] `

Comment: @StephenMuecke; oke but what to do with translations? I think there is no way to do display the translations from the `UmbracoHelper`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'translations'. And I don't use use Umbraco, so not sure what the `_helper.Field()` method does. If your wanting multi-language support, then you can use Resource files.

Comment: If your controller is inherited from "UmbracoController" then you can directly access all UmbracoHelper functionality using Umbraco property. It would be good if you share some info/ code of the controller

Comment: @Nirman: I've got a `SurfaceController` but got only one methode for the to save and mail the forms data.

Comment: I think you should just create the labels yourself instead using helpers.